# Extracting Sequence from fasta file using coordinates list

Tags: r, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a list of sequence starting coordinates and I wanted to retrieve those sequences from the genome fasta file which coordinates are present in the list. I tried using grep and in R but didn't get desired output

list of coordinates

```
10001276
10001433
10002237
10002342
10002617
10002736
10003584
10003832
10005377
1000567
```

which option would be efficient?

Comment: Probably using ``seqtk``

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try [BioPython](https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO):

```
from Bio import SeqIO
record = SeqIO.read("NC_006581.gbk", "genbank")
print("\nPosition 10001276: ", record.seq[10001276,10001276+1])
```

Comment: thanks, I will try and see if its works.